# Are there any websites that hire people to type up written documents?

Tags: freelance

I would like to find work typing out manuscripts and books. I don't want to edit them. If I see a typo, I may correct it, but I am not an editor. I can turn a written document into a typed one. Does anyone know any such websites that hire people to do this type of work?

Comment: There is no paid market for poetry. Also, you'll have to learn to edit your own short stories. The publications that publish short stories expect finished, polished pieces and don't do editing for you.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! You were asking two separate questions here - where to post your short stories, and where you can find work typing out people's manuscripts. I'm certain that the former has already been asked, so I've narrowed this down to just the latter.

Comment: Just to check, you are aware that in this century, a manuscript, though still called that,  isn't actually written by hand but it's a file the writer has typed in their computer, right? Or are you talking about historical handwritten documents? Do you want to work with a digitalisation project or something? I was under the impression that those use OCR software and maybe a human proofreader, but you said you don't want to do proofreading.

Comment: @Divizna Typists are still sought after. See e.g. https://www.randstad.co.uk/career-advice/job-profiles/typist/

Comment: I thought that the asker wants to work with literature. If they're looking into getting a job like those described at the site you link, then yes, those exist, but they're firmly out of the scope of anything this channel is about. Perhaps the [Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask such a question.